# Graphviz - Fixed Node Origin and End Point

Tags: graphviz

Is there any way to ensure that all edges start from the same place on a node, and end on the same node in graphviz (see my primitive mockup)? I've been looking through the graphviz documentation, and I can't seem to find a parameter to fit this use-case.  [image: mockup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for node **ports**, specifically **compass points**.

Ports and compass points are defined in the [dot language grammar](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html). A detailed description with examples can be found in the [dot guide](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf), page 18, "3.1 Node ports":

> A node port is a point where edges can attach to a node.
>
> There are two types of ports. Ports based on the 8 compass points "n", "ne", "e", "se", "s", "sw", "w" or "nw" can be specified for any node.
>
> In addition, nodes with a recordshape can use the record structure to define ports, while HTML-like labels with tables can make any cell a port using the PORT attribute of a  element.

Two examples of using ports with compass points:

```
a:e -> b:w

a -> b [tailport=e, headport=w]
```

See also the [headport](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:headport) and [tailport](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:tailport) attribute description